# how do i solve libilto.so plugin error in compiling kernel?

Tags: android, ubuntu, kernel, android-kernel

I am developing the kernel for android . I tried a lot but I keep getting this error . I tried all the steps systematically yet I am not able to compile my own kernel because i am getting this error whenever I execute the command "make -j3".

```
aarch64-linux-android-gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
```